# WebSphere solution for writing to file system

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

I'm using WebSphere application server and I've database to write my MI data. Now requirement is to write some where even when my database is down or table space exceeds it's limit.

I thought of writing it to a file when db is down but I read some where that it is not suggestible when using WebSphere server as it causes problem in a clustered environment.

Can any one suggest better way to handle this requirement?

Comment: In cluster mode you file must be in a shared directory. But first of all database table space size must be under database administrator control. And If it is exceeded this means administrator don't do her job. If your system database under WebSphere Application Server is the same you will have very big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple.
You should use shared file storage.
It must be available for each cluster member.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. How can I create shared file storage in WebSphere application server?

Comment: this is simple - shared directory that can be reached via unc protocol (eg: \\server\directory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Plausible solution. I'll give a try tomorrow. Thanks again.